# Mixing Boost FOREACH macro and OpenMP parallelization

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, openmp

I currently have a code (in C) with an outer loop that is OpenMP-parallelized (it operates locally on a shared-memory list). I'm rewriting it in C++, and for many things I found the BOOST_FOREACH macro a very nice syntax as loop construct for iterating over a list, array, etc.

My question is: is there a way I can both use that syntax and parallelize the loop OpenMP-style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the terminal is worth 1 kilowords:

```
$ g++ a.cpp -I/opt/boost-1.45.0/include -O -fopenmp   
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:12: error: for statement expected before ‘if’
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should just work. BOOST_FOREACH is just a helper macro for a for loop, so OpenMP should recognize and parallelize that loop.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure... as far as I can see from the header, the BOOST_FOREACH macro expands to more than a for loop, because it first includes a series of `if`-`else`... So, if I put my OpenMP directives right above the macro, they won't be right above the `for` loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply try it, and profile the result?

I would be impressed if OpenMP paralized boost_foreach, as foreach relies heavily on template tricks to deduct the container type. If I were in your position, I'd rewrite the foreach's to use regular for-loops.

Comment: Hell, there are so many wrong things with that answer... Computer science is not an empirical science, for the most part. To the point, if it works on a given system, with a given compiler (and set of options), it gives me no guarantee that it will work on any other system or with any other compiler.

Comment: Science and science, if it is NUM_CORES-3 times faster I'd still be quite sure openMP paralizes the for loop